# How to get VueJS modifiers with PUG

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, pug

How can we get modifiers with Pug?

I tried the following:

```
my-component(:options.sync="addresses")

my-component(':options.sync'="addresses")
```

Both of these give a syntax error, unexpected token.

```
my-component(:options="addresses")
```

Gets compiled but of course misses the modifier in the final HTML.

If that cannot be achieved with pug, is there any way to integrate raw HTML within a PUG template so that I can specify just that component with HTML and the rest with PUG syntax?

Comment: What exactly do you want to be output?  I'm using pug with vue.js and have never had a problem with this.

Comment: Take a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/graham-sportsmgmt/pen/BGPxjj), it renders `my-component(:options="addresses")` to `<my-component :options="addresses"></my-component>`, just as expected.

Comment: Also, the codepen renders `my-component(:options.sync="addresses")` as `<my-component :options.sync="addresses"></my-component>`

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening but it is. I will dig further then :(

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what "Gets compiled but of course misses the modifier in the final HTML." means exactly.  That's a little vague, could you post more details around that?

Comment: @Graham The attribute is `:options` instead of `:options.sync`. So it does not do what I required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this part of your question you can output raw HTML with either the pipe or period characters at the end of your element.

> ...is there any way to integrate raw HTML within a PUG template so that I can specify just that component with HTML and the rest with PUG syntax?

With the pipe at the start of a line you will get the raw output for that line.  For example this will render the exact string after the pipe:

```
| <div>
|   <a href='https://example.com'>Link to site</a>
| </div>
```

The period is used after a block to output all child elements as raw text.  This would output the same HTML as the code block above:

```
div.
  <a href='https://example.com'>Link to site</a>
```